# How to filter values in column by values in other column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I have a dataframe:

```
id    value
a1      0
a1      1
a1      2
a1      3
a2      0
a2      1
a3      0
a3      1
a3      2
a3      3
```

I want to filter id's and leave only those which have value from 0 to 3 (0,1,2,3). So in this example id a2 must be removed since it only has values 0 and 1. So desired result is:

```
id    value
a1      0
a1      1
a1      2
a1      3
a3      0
a3      1
a3      2
a3      3
```

How to to that?

Comment: If you also had a row (a1, 15), should it be returned? (You can edit your question and add that row to the sample data, to make things clearer.)

Comment: @jarlh yes it should

Comment: Do not tag your question with multiple databases.  Are you using MySQL or Presto?  Only tag with the one you are really using.  You should also be clear about whether other values exist outside this range.

Answer (score 1):

A simple aggregation approach would be:

```sql
SELECT id, value
FROM yourTable
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE value IN (0, 1, 2, 3)
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 4
);
```

Comment: thanks, this part ```WHERE value IN (0, 1, 2, 3)``` seems not scalable (if I need from 0 to 1000 I should write 1000 integers)

Comment: @french_fries Well if you need _all_ values from 0 to 1000, then you could use `WHERE value BETWEEN 0 AND 1000`.  If you only need _certain_ values from the range 0 to 1000, that's another story, you would either have to list all values, or specify a series of ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest window functions, especially if you are using Presto.  Assuming the rows have only those four values and the rows are unique:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 4;
```

If values can be outside this range, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(case when value in (0, 1, 2, 3) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 4;
```